# How to make it so that multiple motors respond to

Tags: marlin

I want to make it so that the E1 and E0 do exactly the same as the Y motor and I was wondering if anyone here knew how to do that?

I basically just want to make it so that when the Y motor is triggered, so is the E1 and E0.

I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to use the outputs for E1 and E0 as a second and a third Y-stepper?

Comment: Not really. Because I realise that I could just change the config.h file. What I am actually wanting to do is make E1 and E0 the same. I assume there must be some way I can edit the pins.h file I just don’t know how?

Answer (score 1):

One way to have two E-steppers to do the same work should be to enable `MIXING_EXTRUDER` in `Configuration.h`. I have no experience in this myself, but it is a good starting point.

A second way is to actually connect the two *identical* steppers in parallel. That trick is sometimes used for Z-steppers. I don't expect the current consumption to be an issue. This will require soldering, unless your mainboard has two Z-stepper outputs and you only use one of them. Then move connectors and reconfigure pins.h (or similar file) to use the correct steppers for `Z` and `E`.

A third way is possible if your mainboard has removable stepper driver modules. Remove the `E1` stepper driver from the socket and cut off the `EN`, `DIR` and `STEP` pins. Solder thin but insulated wires between the solder-pads on this one to the `E0` stepper. These are all inputs, so now the second stepper will follow the first perfectly. Soldering shall be done while the stepper driver modules are removed, otherwise the heat might ruin the sockets. (There are more precautions)